# Using SDL for a web application

Tags: c++, django, qt, sdl, sdl-2

I'm currently working on an SDL 2 application (C++) and I have a question. As the title suggests i'm attempting to use SDL as a web app. I wanted to know what the best way to go about this would be. I've put some research into this and the avenues to take would either be:

- Interfacing with python
- Using Wt as a toolkit and layering SDL 2 on top of it.
- Using QT creator and layering SDL 2 on top of it.

Clearly there must be other ways to do this, but my primary concern is the fact that SDL 2 expects some form of a window (SDL_Window) and renderer (SDL_Renderer), will my options help me overcome the hurdle? Or would I have to directly code SDL 2 into python and attempt to use that along with Django (or some other form of web app API) to do as I need?

P.S I'm not looking to get into any other API's other than SDL/Opengl(If I must). I'd like to know if it's possible to get SDL working on a web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run C++ binded with SDL+OpenGL code on a web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327231/is-it-possible-to-run-c-binded-with-sdlopengl-code-on-a-web-browser)

Comment: Yes, it's possible "now". Your question had to wait a few years: https://www.jamesfmackenzie.com/2019/12/01/webassembly-graphics-with-sdl/

Answer (score 10):

It is possible using [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/)

I've succesfully compiled many SDL2+OpenGL projects to JS

Read this page first: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html

The default SDL version is `1.2`. To use SDL2, you have to explicitly tell it to the compiler like this:

```
-s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS="['png']"
```

If you have to use OpenGL 3 features (and/or GLSL newer than 1.0), use this parameter too (requires WebGL 2):

```
-s USE_WEBGL2=1
```

In the code you have to replace the `while(!quit){ ... }` main loop with an `emscripten_set_main_loop` call.

Comment: Instead of using emscripten_set_main_loop, there's another way. Just use emterpreter.

Comment: That will produce a much slower code. Replace the main loop of your game with `emscripten_set_main_loop` and avoid emterpreter if possible

Answer (score 0):

About emscripten. I often use common main_loop with exception handler. It should catch special exception, called for example go_to_mainloop. Additionally, I added function to put function called from main loop and parameter passed to this function on special array/list or other. I also split functions with loop into smaller parts - especially initialization and loop itself.

So - to call internal loop, you put loop function pointer and structure initialized in function created by splitting (initialization function). In next step you only need to throw exception to go to main loop function. Of course - part of function after loop must be putted in stack/array too, before you put loop function. Also, you must create function, witch removes last entry from array/stack/list/etc..

Answer (score -5):

Running C++ applications in a web browser is not normally possible. There are plugins and browsers that support it (like [Google's Native Client](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)), and the capabilities are still very limited. It still depends on the hardware of the machine running it, and the browser it uses. So no, SDL is in no way usable in a web app, and is not meant to be used that way. You may instead take a look at [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/), based on OpenGL ES, which is a standard and is supported by most browser.

Comment: I've checked out NaCl and it's very limited in the type of browsers it can work in. https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial This seems to support SDL, so I don't see that it isn't in any way possible. I will be looking into webgl, thanks.

Comment: Native client was currently deprecated :-( . Google decided to switch to webassembly.

Comment: It is unfortunate Google still indexes this answer as relevant today. WebAssembly  nullifies this answer. See also: https://www.jamesfmackenzie.com/2019/12/01/webassembly-graphics-with-sdl/